Mark recapture with no knowledge of marked individuals
I am a math student working with a group of field biologists. In multiple experiments of mark-recapture of the same population, they claimed that if the number of observations (recaptures) is large enough, it is possible to infer both population size ($N$) and proportion ($p=K/N$) based only on the sample, without prior knowledge of the number of individuals that were originally marked ($K$).
Considering a sample of size $n$ with $k$ marked individuals is drawn from the population, a histogram of the observed proportions is created using jackknifes subsamples. Then a hypergeometric distribution is fitted to the histogram using minimum squares. This leads to a pair of estimated parameters $\hat{p}$ and $\hat{N}$.
I am convinced that under the assumption of $K$ unknown this estimator converges to the sample size ($n$), i.e $\hat{N} \rightarrow n$ (or at least to a value different than $N$). However, I haven't proved it yet.
They tested this estimator with simulated data. My conclusion is that in the simulations the standard deviation of $\hat{N}$ is large enough so that the values of $N$ and $\hat{N}$ sometimes coincide.
I am creating this question to verify whether I am correct. Also, I am not very good explaining myself, and need to create an argument to convince non-specialists that $\hat{N} \rightarrow n$. Thank all of you for your help.

+1 Nice clear explanation. Do you know what estimators they're using to estimate N and p?

They create a histogram of the observed proportions (they make many observations) and they fit a hypergeometric distribution trough minimum squares. Thanks Glen_b.

Better said, they made 1 single (large) observation (size n) and they sub-sample (bootstrap or jackknifes, not entirely sure) this vector to create the histogram.

Do you at least know if you've recaptured the same specimen, i.e. is the mark unique? If not you might be able to estimate $p$ but I don't see how that tells you anything about $N$.

If the individuals were sampled with replacement (without keeping track of already marked individuals) then a more appropriate distribution would be the binomial distribution.

@Josh The data they begin with is the number sampled (n) and the number of those that were marked (m, say)?

@Glen_b The population sizes are $N$ (total, unkown), $K$ (marked, unkown), and the sample sizes are $n$ (total sampled, known), $k$ (marked, known).

@PBulls This is the main issue, I believe this is not enough to estimate $N$. I need to prove that this estimator converges to the sample size, not to the population size.

@Josh It might be worth mentioning your notation for $k$ in the question.

From first principles it is clear that the single observed hypergeometric sample of size $n$ out of which $k$ will be informative about little more than $p=K/N$.  Both $N$ and $K$ will be nearly unidentifiable which can be seen from the fact that the likelihood tends towards a flat ridge along the line given by $K/N=k/n$ as $N$ and $K$ becomes large (this follows from the binomial as a limit of hypergeometic distribution).  The likelihood ridge is illustrated below for  the sample $k=5$ and $n=10$.
It is impossible that the subsampling method employed can produce any information about $N$ beyond the information provided by the above observed likelihood.  Conditional on $n$ and $k$ (that is, conditional on the original sample), it is true that subsamples of size $m$ (assuming that these are also drawn without replacement from the orignal sample) will be independently hypergeometrically distributed but the parameters will be $n,k,m$ rather than $N,K,m$.  So when estimating $N$ by fitting a hypergeomertic distribution to these subsamples, the field biologists are in reality indeed estimating $n$, not $N$.  It is also true that the subsamples hypergeometrically distributed with parameters $N,K,m$ but this is only marginally (that is, when not conditioning on $n$ and $k$).  And marginally, the subsamples are also not independent which makes fitting a hypergeometric distribution to the subsamples invalid when the aim is to estimate $N$.
N <- 1:100
K <- 1:100
n <- 10
k <- 5
contour(N, K, 
        outer(N, K, function(N,K) dhyper(k, K, N-K, n)), 
        xlab="N", ylab="K", nlevels = 50
)
#> Warning in dhyper(k, K, N - K, n): NaNs produced


Created on 2024-06-14 with reprex v2.1.0

Sorry for my late response, I was waiting for further comments. Your answer gave me valuable insights. Thank you Jarle!
